# How to save simplecartjs variables into a database MVC5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, simplecart

I would like to save the items in the columns below into a database and i'm using MVC5.

```
simpleCart({
    cartColumns: [
        { attr: "name" , label: "Name" } ,
        { attr: "price" , label: "Price", view: 'currency' } ,
        { view: "decrement" , label: false , text: "-" } ,
        { attr: "quantity" , label: "Qty" } ,`enter code here`
        { view: "increment" , label: false , text: "+" } ,
        { attr: "total" , label: "SubTotal", view: 'currency' } ,
        { view: "remove" , text: "Remove" , label: false }
    ]
});
```

Basically want to save the cart as a order, but i don't know how to.

Comment: Do you have a model defined that matches the fields and values in that array?

Comment: Yes I do and I can't get the values in the array to insert into the database, I cannot even call them in my controller

Comment: Can you show us some of your code and JavaScript?  What you have already tried?